# How do I get better forecasts for this data

Tags: r, regression, time-series

How do I get better forecasts for my model?  Is the plot supposed to look like this? I am using the code:

```
fit <- auto.arima(blah)
fcast <- forecast(fit,100)
```

[image]

Comment: I undeleted the image because without it, the answers are incomprehensible.

Answer (score 4):

As RSK says, it appears that your data has seasonality. Looking at the x axis, it looks to me as though you might have daily data, since it appears to have a cycle that's roughly 365 long.

When you used ARIMA, it didn't know this. You need to indicate that you're measuring daily values and the natural unit of time is a year. Then it would be able to detect yearly cycles and your prediction line would reflect this.

Unfortunately, I was never successful in using daily or weekly data with various ARIMA tools because there is no fixed frequency. You can't say a year is 365 days, because of leap years. You can't say there are 52 weeks in a year (only adds up to 364 days), especially depending on how you measure weeks (is it a seven-day period, or Sunday-Saturday).

This appears to be accepted by R, but I'm not sure if it does what I hope it does. And some time series routines give errors and will not accept this kind of time series (daily for years):

blah <- ts (blah_data, start=c(2011, 1), freq=365.25)

Bottom line to get a forecast, I'd recommend that you try `StructTS` and `stl` to see if they work for you.

Comment: +1. However, given that there are only about two years of history, I wouldn't worry too much about leap years - any error introduced by using a 365 day period instead of a 365.25 days one is probably swamped by the noise in the series.

Answer (score 4):

Following up on Wayne's answer:  perhaps try a [tbats](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/tbats) model, with 365 day seasonality.  You could also optionally provide a second seasonal period because it looks like there might be a shorter cycle in your data as well (perhaps about 7 days?).

`tbats` models fit exponential smoothing models that use use trigonometric functions to model seasonality.  This allows you to model multiple seasonal periods, and seems to be a better way to model longer seasonal periods.  (How appropriate is it really to compare today to a day exactly 365 days ago?)

You might also want to find a way to explicitly model or remove the spikes in your dataset.

Comment: +1. Especially for the suggestion about modeling the spikes. The data look a lot like daily retail sales with promotions (upward spikes) and availability problems, also known as "Out of Stocks" (the downward spikes).

Comment: c1 =  tbats(blah,use.trend=TRUE,seasonal.periods=7,use.arma.errors=TRUE,use.box.cox=TRUE) Would this be correct?

Comment: @phil12 you can also just specify the `seasonal.periods`, and `tbats` will choose the best specification for each of the other parameters.  Also, your data's biggest period is clearly larger than 7-- I would try specifying `seasonal.periods=265`, AFTER trying to remove the spikes.

Comment: IS there a good explanation for the model. IT seems hard to interpret.

Comment: @phil12 it's a pretty complicated model, and it is hard to interpret.  It's basically decomposing your time series into a trend, multiple seasonal components, and an error term.  If you plot the model, you can see the decomposition.  It's probably a good idea to read the paper: http://robjhyndman.com/papers/ComplexSeasonality.pdf

Answer (score 2):

your time series seem to consist of two components: slow (and maybe seasonal) and fast. There are exponential smoothing family of models that might help (by decomposing your time series into its building blocks). 
Additionally, if there are certain exogenous factors that might influence your time series, you can use them as explanatory variables in explaining parts of variation.
I hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

As Wayne properly points out, using ARIMA will not work here.  You should consider a regression with 6 daily dummies and 11 monthly dummies, trend(s), outliers adjusted, level shift(s), and changes in seasonality of the daily dummies (ie seasonal pulse).  You can also test for special days of the month and holidays(ie leads and lags).